# incomparable type in java

Tags: java

I have got this code, and I get an error `incomparable types: java.lang.String and int`, for this line of code 
    `if ((this.name.String.compareTo(obj.name == 0)) && (this.age = obj.age))`

The method is this:

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
    int result;
    AnyClass obj = (AnyClass)o;
    if ((this.name.String.compareTo(obj.name == 0)) && (this.age = obj.age))
    {
        result = 0;
    }
   else if (this.name.compareTo(obj.name) > 0)
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this - `this.name.String`? Is it a typo here?

Comment: I am not exactly sure, I had been given this code, it was initially this.name.compareTo() but found somewhere else this.name.String thought it might help, this.name.compareTo() gave the same error

Comment: If this is an implementation of `Comparable` for `AnyClass`, the signature is "off": it should be an `AnyClass` argument, not an `Object`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that position of your bracket isn't correct,

```
this.name.String.compareTo(obj.name == 0))
```

obj.name == 0 is the place where you probably compare String (name) to int (0). I guess you wanted to use compareTo on obj.name and then check if it's equal to zero.

I also think that in the second part

```
(this.age = obj.age)
```

You wanted to use == instead of =, so I think that the code you wanted to use is:

```
((this.name.compareTo(obj.name)==0) && (this.age == obj.age))
```

Comment: Correct, but remove the `String` from the `this.name.String.compareTo(obj.name)==0)`

Comment: and I had to remove String just like Fallup said

Comment: @PawełChorążyk You are welcome, was typing the same answer as you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare a string to an integer :)

You *can* convert the string "001" into the integer "1"; or the integer "1" into the string "1".

See [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) or [Integer.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

Answer (score 1):

`compareTo` takes in Objec reference(a string in your case) as argument. But your code `compareTo(obj.name == 0)` passes in boolean which is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code

```
 if ((this.name.String.compareTo(obj.name == 0)) && (this.age = obj.age))
```

is actually supposed to read like this

```
 if ((this.name.compareTo(obj.name) == 0) && (this.age == obj.age))
```

Changing where the `== 0` is (and changing the second `=` to an `==`) makes this code make sense.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems with this implementation. It looks like this is an implementation of `Comparable` for class `AnyClass` which means the signature is wrong.

`AnyClass` should implement `Comparable<AnyClass>`, and the code should look like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(AnyClass other)
{
    int ret = name.compareTo(other.name);
    return ret != 0 ? ret : Integer.compare(age, other.age);
}
```

If you use Guava:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(AnyClass other)
{
    return ComparisonChain.start().compare(name, other.name)
       .compare(age, other.age).result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`((this.name.String.compareTo(obj.name == 0)) && (this.age = obj.age))`

obj.name is a String, and 0 is an int. That's where you're getting the error

Answer (score 0):

`obj.name` is String and you are comparing it with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you explain your intention with the code. The first error seems to be the comparison in `compareTo` `obj.name == 0`.

Try

```
if ((this.name.String.compareTo(obj.name) == 0) && (this.age == obj.age))
```

Which is what I guess you want to achieve.